# Android Gradle: rename/disable default build type

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-build

Can the pre-defined build-types somehow being renamed?

We use some custom build types that represent our internal staging setup (DEV/TEST/LIVE) and do not need the build in buildTypes (release/debug). Can these somehow being renamed or disabled when calling *`assemble`*?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
import com.android.builder.core.BuilderConstants
android.variantFilter { variant ->
    def build = variant.buildType.name
    if (build == BuilderConstants.DEBUG || build == BuilderConstants.RELEASE) {
        variant.setIgnore(true)
    }
}
```

Note that the very first time importing the project Android Studio will pick any [variant named debug else it will pick the first build variant in alphabetical order](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/adt/idea/+/71dc83646b142ef3e96150c42f00575094184fed%5E%21/#F0), which may not be the one you prefer as the default.

Comment: Where do I put the import statement?

Comment: @TrentPierce with Groovy, you can put the import statement anywhere at 'top-level' (i.e. not inside `android {…}` or any other block)..

Answer (score 0):

One solution i have come up with is to acctually just assemble the specifics and not run assemble. Which assembles all.

Try out gradle tasks to see the possibilites

But im looking for a better solution too, one that can be defined in the gradle.build file.